# Nginx Recursive Matching by directory name

Tags: css, wordpress, nginx, fonts

I'm setting up Nginx to host a variety of WordPress sites. I'm blocking access to the theme and plugin files by default for security reasons, but I need to permit access to all CSS and Font files in the wp-content/(plugins|themes). I tried this to allow all files in a directory called css or font.

```
location ~* /wp-content/plugins/*/(css|font)/*
```

It doesn't seem to work when the plugin has fonts two directories or more deep. (ex. plugins/name/include/font/)

How do I write the location to permit the handling of multiple directories between plugins|themes and their font|css directories?

Comment: If no one else knows (I don't know much about WP), an alternative idea might be to not do this via nginx, but to just symlink the plugins/css and plugins/font locations.

Comment: You need to write it as a regular expression. Maybe: `location ~* ^/wp-content/plugins/.*/(css|font)/` will do what you want.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid regular expressions for it since the load for those are higher, but I'm okay if that's the only solution.

Comment: The problem with the symlink solution is that it doesn't solve the problem of doing this once for all the various scenarios. I could more easily maintain the nginx configuration of each individually than maintain the symlinks for all this and the forked plugin and theme code.